# Will memory of dataframe created in function be released after function call in pyspark

Tags: memory, pyspark

Suppose I have source code like this:

```
my_function():
    df = Spark.createDataFrame(Data, schema)
    # some transformation inside this dataframe
    df1 = transformation_1(df)
    df2 = transformation_2(df1)
    df3 = transformation_2(df2)

   return df3

if __name__ == "__main__":
    df = my_function()
    df.collect()
```

My question is: is memory occupied by df, df1 and f2 be garbage collected after function call df = my_function()? Or they will stay in the memory until the program completes.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, since you don't cache anything, all df1, df2, and df3 would be created "on the fly" and would be released right after the program is completed. In other words, `df = my_function()` would **not** store data on memory.